# Every point of the cantor set $F$ is a cluster point of both $F$ and it's complement $F^c $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Every point of the cantor set $F$ is a cluster point of both $F$ and it's complement $  F^c$

**Attempt:**

> $(a)~~$  First proving that every point of $F$ is a cluster point of $F$.

Suppose $x \in F$. Then let us suppose there exists a neighborhood of $x$ that does not contain any member of $x$ which means $x$ is an isolated point which contradicts the fact that $x \in$ closed intervals in $\mathbb R$.

Hence, our assumption is wrong and every point in $F$ is a cluster point of $F$.

Did I do it correctly?

> $(b)~~$ Proving that every point in $F$ is a cluster point of $ F^c$

I have an idea that when you keep dividing the intervals to $\dfrac {1}{3}rd$ everytimes, the closed intervals get so tiny that ultimately every member of $F$ must also be a cluster point of $  F^c$.

But, how do I prove this mathematically?

Thank you for your help .

Comment: The Cantor Set is closed, hence it contains all its cluster points.

Comment: yes.. but, how do we prove that every cluster point of the cantor set is a cluster point of it's complement as well?

Comment: When doing topology, denoting the complement of a set by $\bar{A}$ is a bad idea, since $\overline{\Omega}$ is the standard notation for the closure of $\Omega$. Better use $\complement F$, $F^c$, or $[0,1]\setminus F$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I have corrected it

Comment: The cluster points of a closed set are the boundary points as well

Comment: @DanielFischer Any hints please for proving part (b)?

Comment: @DanielFischer, I have edited the comment, actually this was what I mean't

Comment: Your argument for a) isn't correct. Why "which contradicts the fact that $x\in$ closed intervals in $\mathbb{R}$"? The easiest way to see both is, I think, to consider the sequence $(F_n)$ of unions of intervals of length $3^{-n}$. Every endpoint of an interval making up $F_n$ belongs to $F$ (and many many more points). So if you look at the neighbourhood $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$ of $x$, choose an $n$ such that $3^{-n} < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Yeah, I think I get the idea .. But, regarding the argument that "$x \in $ closed intervals in $\mathbb R$". An isolated point cannot belong to a closed interval (due to the Archimedean principle ) and cantor set is the union of closed intervals. Isn't this reasoning correct?

Comment: Cantor set is *not* a union of closed intervals. It is the **intersection** of unions of closed intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the Cantor set $F$ is nowhere dense, i.e, it doesn't contain any intervals. Thus any neighborhood of any point in $F$ intersects its complement.

Also note that for any $x\in F$, the ternary expansion of $x$ contains only $0$ and $2$. Now you can flip the $i$-th digits to obtain the required sequence in $F$ approaching $x$.